# Why std::is_function<T> is causing compilation error?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, static-assert

Hi I was trying to implement a C++ concept-like feature (C++14) in C++11. The idea is just to write the wrapper function for `std::for_each()` algorithm where I just check whether the 3rd argument is a function or not. So I wrote the following code, however I am not able to compile it as it should be. I am using Ubuntu12.04 with gcc4.8.1.

test_1.cpp

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>


void  display(int& val) {
    std::cout <<val<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr   bool  Is_valid_function(T& a)  {
        return std::is_function<T>::value; 
}


template<typename T>
void  check_valid_function(T& a)  {
        static_assert(Is_valid_function(a), "Not The Valid Function");
}



template <class InputIterator, class Function>
Function my_for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f) {
/* Concept Like Implementation to just check whether f is function or not */
            check_valid_function(f);
            return for_each(first, last, f) ;
}


void learn_static_assert_and_typetraits(void)
{
        std::vector<int> vec_x{1,2,3,4,5};
        my_for_each(vec_x.begin(), vec_x.end(), display);
    }


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
        learn_static_assert_and_typetraits();
        return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error from which I can see that the `static_assert()` fails which is not correct as `display` is valid function.

## Compilation Error

```
test_3.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void check_valid_function(T&) [with T = void (*)(int&)]’:
test_3.cpp:27:26:   required from ‘Function my_for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, Function) [with InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Function = void (*)(int&)]’
test_3.cpp:35:50:   required from here
test_3.cpp:19:3: error: static assertion failed: Not The Valid Function
   static_assert(Is_valid_function(a), "Not The Valid Function");
   ^
```

---

However if I do the same thing for the other type_traits function, I am getting the following error which is correct and expected.

test_2.cpp

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr   bool Is_floating_point(T& a) {
        return std::is_floating_point<T>::value; 
}


template<typename T>
void  f(T& a)  {
        static_assert(Is_floating_point(a), "Non-Float Type  Data");
}


void learn_static_assert_and_typetraits(void) {
        float y{10.0};
        f(y);
        int x{100};
        f(x);
}


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
        learn_static_assert_and_typetraits();
        return 0;
}
```

## Compiler Output

```
test_2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void f(T&) [with T = int]’:
test_2.cpp:19:6:   required from here
test_2.cpp:11:3: error: static assertion failed: Non-Float Type  Data
   static_assert(Is_floating_point(a), "Non-Float Type  Data");
   ^
```

## Question

So, I wanted to understand why my first program is not working as it should be, whether there is bug in my code/understanding or it is something else. I hope the above data would be sufficient to understand my question. However if anyone wants some additional data, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Function>
Function my_for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f)
```

invoked via:

```
my_for_each(vec_x.begin(), vec_x.end(), display);
```

This deduces `Function` (of `my_for_each`) to be a *function pointer*; for

```
void  display(int& val)
```

the deduced type is `void(*)(int&)`. The type trait `std::is_function` however checks if the passed type is a *function type*, not a *function pointer* type.

---

One solution is to remove the pointer:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr   bool  Is_valid_function(T& a)  {
        return std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value; 
}
```

But, as clang++ reveals, this still isn't sufficient:

```
template<typename T>
void  check_valid_function(T& a)  {
        static_assert(Is_valid_function(a), "Not The Valid Function");
}
```

`a` as a function parameter (even if `check_valid_function` was `constexpr`!) is *not* a compile-time constant, therefore it may not appear in a constant expression (inside the function body). Hence, `Is_valid_function(a)` may not appear as the check for the `static_assert`. It might be possible to use something similar to `declval`, e.g.

```
static_assert(Is_valid_function( declval<T&>() ), "Not The Valid Function");
```

but unfortunately, `declval` is *not* `constexpr`, and I don't know how to write a `constexpr` version. So, you could pass a pointer instead:

```
static_assert(Is_valid_function(static_cast<T*>(nullptr)),
              "Not a valid function");
```

For this, you need to rewrite `Is_valid_function` as follows:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr   bool  Is_valid_function(T*)  {
        return std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value; 
}
```

*Note:* the passed argument here is a *pointer to a pointer to a function*, but the parameter `T*` deduced `T` to be a *pointer to a function*, as before (hence the change in the signature). You might want to reflect that in the function name, if you choose this solution.

---

Other issues:

1. Relying on ADL for Standard Library algorithms

   ```
   return for_each(first, last, f) ;
   ```

   As far as I can see, this relies on ADL. But the iterators (and the function) are not required to be in namespace `std` (even for `vector::iterator` etc.), so you shouldn't rely on ADL:

   ```
   return std::for_each(first, last, f);
   ```
2. Use of non-const refs for functions that don't need to modify their arguments, e.g.

   ```
   constexpr   bool  Is_valid_function(T& a)
   ```

   If you don't need to modify an argument, you should either pass it by value or by const reference, e.g.

   ```
   constexpr   bool  Is_valid_function(T const& a)
   ```
3. "Wrong check" If this code is just for educational purposes, this isn't an issue. However, the check if the passed argument is of a function type is the "wrong check" when trying to check if the argument valid for a Standard Library algorithm. You should rather check whether `f(*first)` is well-formed. This allows for function objects and checks if the argument type is "valid".

Comment: Thank You Very Much DyP for your response. I would wait for your further response on this. Btw i should have noticed that compiler message where deduced type was void(*)(int&) which is function pointer and not the function type......

Comment: @mantosh4u Already updated my answer ;) But clang++ revealed another issue, give me a second..

Comment: Yes,this piece of code is just for educational purposes. And i was aware about std:: namespace should have been used. I just missed that part... However i got it completely what you are trying to explain to me.... thank you very much and i would again wait for your further response....

Comment: @mantosh4u Ok, now it compiles with both, g++4.8.1 and an early clang++3.4

Comment: `template<class T> constexpr add_reference_t<T> declval();` should work

Comment: @Xeo It's not defined; I think the function is odr-used. Also, "an invocation of an undefined `constexpr` function" may not appear in a constant expression [expr.const]/2.

Comment: Ah, right, there was that. He should just stick to proper traits.